# using unicode characters in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

well, I have this problem in Python: I need to store a path directory in a string variable. Now the path may contain both latin and greek characters. 
This variable is later gonna be used as path directory indeed, managing files etc.

When I give the value (the path) to the variable through an input() function from the console it works fine. But when I set the variable value directly, something like this:

```
path = 'F:\Λήψεις'
```

I get an error message:

```
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xcb' in file C:\Users\kostas\My Documents\LiClipse Workspace\auto_file\auto_file.py on line 127, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

No such problem appears (or any other problem) when my path is all ascii:

```
path = 'F:\Downloads'
```

I'm using Windows, Liclipse, Python 3...

I read the documentation but didn't understand something more than it should work because Python 3 has UTF-8 encoding by default which includes greek characters.

So my question is how can I make `path = 'F:\Λήψεις'` to work?

Comment: Atleast show us your complete code? Have you set the encoding for the file correctly?

Comment: What editor do you use? What encoding do you actually use for the source? Can you configure the editor to use UTF-8? What coding have you specified for the source? If you for example use ISO 8859-7 for encoding (which you could have used) and have specified UTF-8 coding that would be expected outcome. Note that in python3 UTF-8 is default while in python2 ASCII is default.

Comment: Also note that backslashes need to be escaped in order not to be confused with escape sequences. It should be `'F:\\Downloads'` for example.